# Converting a CGGradient to a CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, paintcode

I'm using a PaintCode StyleKit to generate a bunch of gradients, but PaintCode exports them as a `CGGradient`. I wanted to add these gradients a `layer`. Is it possible to convert a `CGGradient` to a `CAGradientLayer`?

Comment: Do you *need* to convert it for some specific reason? You could draw the CGGradient in a UIView.

Comment: Correction: PaintCode generates `PCGradient` class that wraps the `CGGradientRef`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The point of a CAGradientLayer is that you get to describe to it the gradient you want and it draws the gradient for you. You are already past that step; you have *already* described the gradient you want (to PaintCode *instead* of to a CAGradientLayer) and thus you already *have* the gradient you want. Thus, it is silly for you even to *want* to use a CAGradientLayer, since if you were going to do that, why did you use PaintCode in the first place? Just draw the CGGradient, itself, into an image, a view, or even a layer.

Comment: Partially true, but when you create whole app in the PaintCode and you want just one gradient used in `CAShapeLayer` (for animation or something), it is a valid request to be able to get colors and locations separately. We will look at this.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the colors out of a CGGradient, but you can use the same values to set the CAGradientLayer's `colors` and `locations` properties. Perhaps it would help for you to modify the generated `PCGradient` class to keep the colors and locations around as NSArrays that you can pass into CAGradientLayer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be important if you have a library of gradients and only occasionally need to use a gradient in one of the two formats.

Yes, it is possible, but requires some math to convert from a regular coordinate system (with x values from 0 to the width and y values from 0 to the height) to the coordinate system used by CAGradientLayer (with x values from 0 to 1 and y values from 0 to 1). And it requires some more math (quite complex) to get the slope right.

The distance from 0 to 1 for x will depend on the width of the original rectangle. And the distance from 0 to 1 for y will depend on the height of the original rectangle. So:

```
let convertedStartX = startX/Double(width)
let convertedStartY = startY/Double(height)
let convertedEndX = endX/Double(width)
let convertedEndY = endY/Double(height)

let intermediateStartPoint = CGPoint(x:convertedStartX,y:convertedStartY)
let intermediateEndPoint = CGPoint(x:convertedEndX,y:convertedEndY)
```

This works if your original rectangle was a square. If not, the slope of the line that defines the angle of the gradient will be wrong! To fix this see the excellent answer here: [CAGradientLayer diagonal gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821631/cagradientlayer-diagonal-gradient)

If you pick up the utility from there, then you can set your final converted start and end points as follows, starting with the already-adjusted point values from above:

```
let fixedStartEnd:(CGPoint,CGPoint) = LinearGradientFixer.fixPoints(start: intermediateStartPoint, end: intermediateEndPoint, bounds: CGSize(width:width,height:height))

let myGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
myGradientLayer.startPoint = fixedStartEnd.0
myGradientLayer.endPoint = fixedStartEnd.1
```

Here's code for a full Struct that you can use to store gradient data and get back CGGradients or CAGradientLayers as needed:

```
import UIKit

struct UniversalGradient {

    //Doubles are more precise than CGFloats for the
    //calculations needed to convert start and end
    //to CAGradientLayers 1...0 format

    var startX: Double
    var startY: Double
    var endX: Double
    var endY: Double

    let options: CGGradientDrawingOptions = [.drawsBeforeStartLocation, .drawsAfterEndLocation]

    //for CAGradientLayer
    var colors: [UIColor]
    var locations: [Double]

    //computed conversions
    private var myCGColors: [CGColor] {
        return self.colors .map {color in color.cgColor}
    }

    private var myCGFloatLocations: [CGFloat] {
        return self.locations .map {location in CGFloat(location)}
    }

    //computed properties
    var gradient: CGGradient {
        return CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: myCGColors as CFArray, locations: myCGFloatLocations)!
    }

    var start: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: startX,y: startY)
    }
    var end: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: endX,y: endY)
    }

    //can't use computed property here
    //since we need details of the specific environment's bounds to be passed in
    //so this will be an instance function

    func gradientLayer(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> CAGradientLayer {

        //convert location x and y values from full coordinates to 0...1 for start and end
        //this works great for position, but it gets the slope incorrect if the view is not square

        //this is because the gradient is not drawn with the final scale
        //it is drawn while the view is square, and then it gets stretched, changing the angle
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821631/cagradientlayer-diagonal-gradient

        let convertedStartX = startX/Double(width)
        let convertedStartY = startY/Double(height)
        let convertedEndX = endX/Double(width)
        let convertedEndY = endY/Double(height)

        let intermediateStartPoint = CGPoint(x:convertedStartX,y:convertedStartY)
        let intermediateEndPoint = CGPoint(x:convertedEndX,y:convertedEndY)

        let fixedStartEnd:(CGPoint,CGPoint) = LinearGradientFixer.fixPoints(start: intermediateStartPoint, end: intermediateEndPoint, bounds: CGSize(width:width,height:height))

        let myGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        myGradientLayer.startPoint = fixedStartEnd.0
        myGradientLayer.endPoint = fixedStartEnd.1

        myGradientLayer.locations = self.locations .map {location in NSNumber(value: location)}
        myGradientLayer.colors = self.colors .map {color in color.cgColor}

        return myGradientLayer
    }

}
```