# CAGradientLayer diagonal gradient

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cagradientlayer

[image]

I use the following CAGradientLayer:

```
let layer = CAGradientLayer()
layer.colors = [
    UIColor.redColor().CGColor,
    UIColor.greenColor().CGColor,
    UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
]
layer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1)
layer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0)
layer.locations = [0.0, 0.6, 1.0]
```

But when I set bounds property for the layer, it just stretches a square gradient. I need a result like in Sketch 3 app image (see above).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Share the frame size also

Comment: It doesn't matter actually, but 320x60 is a good example.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Update:** Use context.drawLinearGradient() instead of CAGradientLayer in a [manner similar to the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40345259). It will draw gradients that are consistent with Sketch/Photoshop.

If you absolutely must use CAGradientLayer, then here is the math you'll need to use...

---

It took some time to figure out, but from careful observation, I found out that Apple's implementation of gradients in CAGradientLayer is pretty odd:

1. First it converts the view to a square.
2. Then it applies the gradient using start/end points.
3. The middle gradient will indeed form a 90 degree angle in this resolution.
4. Finally, it squishes the view down to the original size.

This means that the middle gradient will no longer form a 90 degree angle in the new size. This contradicts the behavior of virtually every other paint application: Sketch, Photoshop, etc.

If you want to implement start/end points as it works in Sketch, you'll need to translate the start/end points to account for the fact that Apple is going to squish the view.

---

## Steps to perform (Diagrams)

[image]
[image]
[image]

## Code

```
import UIKit

/// Last updated 4/3/17.
/// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43176174 for more information.
public enum LinearGradientFixer {
  public static func fixPoints(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint, bounds: CGSize) -> (CGPoint, CGPoint) {
    // Naming convention:
    // - a: point a
    // - ab: line segment from a to b
    // - abLine: line that passes through a and b
    // - lineAB: line that passes through A and B
    // - lineSegmentAB: line segment that passes from A to B

    if start.x == end.x || start.y == end.y {
      // Apple's implementation of horizontal and vertical gradients works just fine
      return (start, end)
    }

    // 1. Convert to absolute coordinates
    let startEnd = LineSegment(start, end)
    let ab = startEnd.multiplied(multipliers: (x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height))
    let a = ab.p1
    let b = ab.p2

    // 2. Calculate perpendicular bisector
    let cd = ab.perpendicularBisector

    // 3. Scale to square coordinates
    let multipliers = calculateMultipliers(bounds: bounds)
    let lineSegmentCD = cd.multiplied(multipliers: multipliers)

    // 4. Create scaled perpendicular bisector
    let lineSegmentEF = lineSegmentCD.perpendicularBisector

    // 5. Unscale back to rectangle
    let ef = lineSegmentEF.divided(divisors: multipliers)

    // 6. Extend line
    let efLine = ef.line

    // 7. Extend two lines from a and b parallel to cd
    let aParallelLine = Line(m: cd.slope, p: a)
    let bParallelLine = Line(m: cd.slope, p: b)

    // 8. Find the intersection of these lines
    let g = efLine.intersection(with: aParallelLine)
    let h = efLine.intersection(with: bParallelLine)

    if let g = g, let h = h {
      // 9. Convert to relative coordinates
      let gh = LineSegment(g, h)
      let result = gh.divided(divisors: (x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height))
      return (result.p1, result.p2)
    }
    return (start, end)
  }

  private static func unitTest() {
    let w = 320.0
    let h = 60.0
    let bounds = CGSize(width: w, height: h)
    let a = CGPoint(x: 138.5, y: 11.5)
    let b = CGPoint(x: 151.5, y: 53.5)
    let ab = LineSegment(a, b)
    let startEnd = ab.divided(divisors: (x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height))
    let start = startEnd.p1
    let end = startEnd.p2

    let points = fixPoints(start: start, end: end, bounds: bounds)

    let pointsSegment = LineSegment(points.0, points.1)
    let result = pointsSegment.multiplied(multipliers: (x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height))

    print(result.p1) // expected: (90.6119039567129, 26.3225059181603)
    print(result.p2) // expected: (199.388096043287, 38.6774940818397)
  }
}

private func calculateMultipliers(bounds: CGSize) -> (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
  if bounds.height <= bounds.width {
    return (x: 1, y: bounds.width/bounds.height)
  } else {
    return (x: bounds.height/bounds.width, y: 1)
  }
}

private struct LineSegment {
  let p1: CGPoint
  let p2: CGPoint

  init(_ p1: CGPoint, _ p2: CGPoint) {
    self.p1 = p1
    self.p2 = p2
  }

  init(p1: CGPoint, m: CGFloat, distance: CGFloat) {
    self.p1 = p1

    let line = Line(m: m, p: p1)
    let measuringPoint = line.point(x: p1.x + 1)
    let measuringDeltaH = LineSegment(p1, measuringPoint).distance

    let deltaX = distance/measuringDeltaH
    self.p2 = line.point(x: p1.x + deltaX)
  }

  var length: CGFloat {
    let dx = p2.x - p1.x
    let dy = p2.y - p1.y
    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
  }
  var distance: CGFloat {
    return p1.x <= p2.x ? length : -length
  }
  var midpoint: CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: (p1.x + p2.x)/2, y: (p1.y + p2.y)/2)
  }
  var slope: CGFloat {
    return (p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x)
  }
  var perpendicularSlope: CGFloat {
    return -1/slope
  }
  var line: Line {
    return Line(p1, p2)
  }
  var perpendicularBisector: LineSegment {
    let p1 = LineSegment(p1: midpoint, m: perpendicularSlope, distance: -distance/2).p2
    let p2 = LineSegment(p1: midpoint, m: perpendicularSlope, distance: distance/2).p2
    return LineSegment(p1, p2)
  }

  func multiplied(multipliers: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)) -> LineSegment {
    return LineSegment(
      CGPoint(x: p1.x * multipliers.x, y: p1.y * multipliers.y),
      CGPoint(x: p2.x * multipliers.x, y: p2.y * multipliers.y))
  }
  func divided(divisors: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)) -> LineSegment {
    return multiplied(multipliers: (x: 1/divisors.x, y: 1/divisors.y))
  }
}

private struct Line {
  let m: CGFloat
  let b: CGFloat

  /// y = mx+b
  init(m: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
    self.m = m
    self.b = b
  }

  /// y-y1 = m(x-x1)
  init(m: CGFloat, p: CGPoint) {
    // y = m(x-x1) + y1
    // y = mx-mx1 + y1
    // y = mx + (y1 - mx1)
    // b = y1 - mx1
    self.m = m
    self.b = p.y - m*p.x
  }

  init(_ p1: CGPoint, _ p2: CGPoint) {
    self.init(m: LineSegment(p1, p2).slope, p: p1)
  }

  func y(x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return m*x + b
  }

  func point(x: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y(x: x))
  }

  func intersection(with line: Line) -> CGPoint? {
    // Line 1: y = mx + b
    // Line 2: y = nx + c
    // mx+b = nx+c
    // mx-nx = c-b
    // x(m-n) = c-b
    // x = (c-b)/(m-n)
    let n = line.m
    let c = line.b
    if m-n == 0 {
      // lines are parallel
      return nil
    }
    let x = (c-b)/(m-n)
    return point(x: x)
  }
}
```

## Proof it works regardless of rectangle size

I tried this with a view `size=320x60`, `gradient=[red@0,green@0.5,blue@1]`, `startPoint = (0,1)`, and `endPoint = (1,0)`.

#### Sketch 3:

[image]

#### Actual generated iOS screenshot using the code above:

[image]

Note that the angle of the green line looks 100% accurate. The difference lies in how the red and blue are blended. I can't tell if that's because I'm calculating the start/end points incorrectly, or if it's just a difference in how Apple blends gradients vs. how Sketch blends gradients.

Comment: Very nice answer, but I think your thoughts about “conversion to square” are not exact. Since `startPoint` and `endPoint` are in unit coordinates (from 0 to 1), I think they also _interpolate_ them in unit coordinates when drawing the gradient. This creates the effect of stretched or resized bitmap, but I’m pretty sure no intermediate steps are taken to achieve this result.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the math to fix the endPoint

```
let width = bounds.width
let height = bounds.height
let dx = endPoint.x - startPoint.x
let dy = endPoint.y - startPoint.y
if width == 0 || height == 0 || width == height || dx == 0 || dy == 0 {
  return
}
let ux = dx * width / height
let uy = dy * height / width
let coef = (dx * ux + dy * uy) / (ux * ux + uy * uy)
endPoint = CGPoint(x: startPoint.x + coef * ux, y: startPoint.y + coef * uy)
```

Answer (score -2):

Full code of `layoutSubviews` method is

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let gradientOffset = self.bounds.height / self.bounds.width / 2

    self.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5 + gradientOffset)
    self.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0.5 - gradientOffset)
    self.gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
}
```

Comment: That's closer, but still far off from what Sketch gives you.

Comment: The actual formula that works with any rectangle size seems to require a lot more math than that. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43176174/35690) for my solution.