# How would I add the shadows to a UIView gradient attached to the mainview in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, shadow

I'm trying to add a custom shadow to my uiview with a gradient in a collection cell, but I seem to be doing things backwards... I added this class EHGradientView to my mainview in UICollectionView. And by changing the class that seemed to work on my individual items. But the shadow is proving difficult.

```
IBDesignable
class EHGradientView: UIView {


        override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
            return CAGradientLayer.self
        }

        private var gLayer: CAGradientLayer {
            return self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
        }

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            commonInit()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            commonInit()
        }

        func commonInit() {

            gLayer.type = .axial

            gLayer.colors = [
                UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.46, blue: 0.467, alpha: 1).cgColor,

                UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.36, blue: 0.369, alpha: 1).cgColor

            ]
            gLayer.locations = [0, 1]
            gLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.25, y: 0.5)
            gLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)

            // exaggerated colors so it's obvious

            gLayer.cornerRadius = 28

            shadow()


        }

      func shadow() {
         var shadows = UIView()

        shadows.frame = frame

        shadows.clipsToBounds = false

        addSubview(shadows)


        let shadowPath0 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shadows.bounds, cornerRadius: 10)

        let layer0 = CALayer()

        layer0.shadowPath = shadowPath0.cgPath

        layer0.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.36, blue: 0.369, alpha: 0.4).cgColor

        layer0.shadowOpacity = 1

        layer0.shadowRadius = 20

        layer0.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)

        layer0.bounds = shadows.bounds

        layer0.position = shadows.center

        shadows.layer.addSublayer(layer0)


        var shapes = UIView()

        shapes.frame = frame

        shapes.clipsToBounds = true

        addSubview(shapes)


        let layer1 = CALayer()

        layer1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor

        layer1.bounds = shapes.bounds

        layer1.position = shapes.center

        shapes.layer.addSublayer(layer1)


        shapes.layer.cornerRadius = 10



    }
```

This is the shadow code I keep trying to combine to it so that the shadow appears UNDERNEATH it and ends up looking like this. [image]

Instead what I'm getting is this:

[image]

Comment: Please check this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253036/swift-ui-button-shadow-gradient

Comment: I misspoke. I'm adding it to the UIView that the gradient is attached to.

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help you.

```
backgroundColor = .systemPink
layer.cornerRadius = 20
layer.masksToBounds = false
layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
layer.shadowRadius = 9.0
layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 5)
```

[image: modified properties values and got this result. May this help you.]

Comment: was this expected as per screenshot?

Comment: I don't know where to put this code. Where in my code does this apply? Especially since I have two layers.

Comment: Create a funtion containing above code and call that function in  override init(frame: CGRect) method.