# Add shadow with linear gradient swift

Tags: swift, layer, shadow

I am trying to add a shadow (picture below)
[image]
but I have result like this
[image]

code:

```
func addShadow() {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowRadius = 10
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0 , height: 5)
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0,
                                                     y: bounds.maxY - layer.shadowRadius - 10,
                                                     width: bounds.width,
                                                     height: layer.shadowRadius)).cgPath
    }
```

how do I change my code to get correct result? It seems it has to be 3 colors like in linear gradient [.white, .purple, .white] does it?

Comment: maybe this link be helpful: https://github.com/PierrePerrin/ShadowView

Comment: https://github.com/benboecker/ShadowView

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in two ways. You can change the `x` and `width` of `UIBezierPath` in such a way that the shadow comes in the centre of the view. Check below code snippet:

```
layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: bounds.width / 3,
                                             y: bounds.maxY - layer.shadowRadius - 10,
                                             width: bounds.width / 3,
                                             height: layer.shadowRadius)).cgPath
```

Here width is divided into 3 parts (white, purple, white) and BezierPath's `x` starts from end of first part. This will solve the purpose as the corner shadow colours are white.

The other way would be creating gradient. It is already answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253036/swift-ui-button-shadow-gradient) SO thread.

Comment: the reason creating gradient is not looking available is the same color on top and bottom of gradient frame. The color should become duller from top to bottom

https://imgtr.ee/image/Dr70U