# How to make mesh gradient in UiKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, gradient

I’d like to make mesh gradient for views background like this [image: gradient]

How can I do it with UIKit? Maybe there is proprieties in CAGradientLayer

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821631/cagradientlayer-diagonal-gradientCheck this